# How to create a Parameter column/Editable column for a table or matrix visual?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerapps

I need a column on a table visual or matrix visual in which values can be inserted or edited on the published dashboard only for visual purposes (without persisting the data or writing it anywhere). Like inserting a parameter or a value on an Excel table.

The table has a Proposed Purchase column, and I just need an editable column next to it so the user inputs the Real Purchase they intend to make, just so the Total at the end of the table shows the sum of the Real Purchases inserted on each row.

ex.:

```
        Proposed Purchase | Real Purchase

                 7000     | *blank field where the user can input a value*

                 5500     | *blank field where the user can input a value*

Total:          12500     | *sum of the inserted values*
```

If anyone knows a solution to this or a component I can use I appreciate it.

Comment: [What-if paramters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-what-if) might work.

Comment: yeah, but it's like an entire column of What-if parameters on a 40+ rows table. I haven't found a way to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

If [what-if parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-what-if) are insufficient, then you need a more robust solution like:

[PowerApps Custom Visual](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2019/09/integrating-powerapps-and-power-bi-to-build-multifaceted-apps/)

or else a product like

[Power On's Visual Planner for Power BI](https://poweronbi.com/powerbi-visual-planning/)